# Question about the input in a command line program

Tags: java, command-line

I want the program to do something when I enter this in the command line:

`connect Xm`
`connect Xn`

connect is a string and Xm (or Xn) is an int (the X which is variable) and a string (m or n, the user decides which one he takes). So for example connect 5m should get accepted.

Doing connect 5 m instead isn't allowed. Xm or Xn is both an int and a string so how can I make the program recognize it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this will solve your issue

```
String v = "connect 5m";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(connect\\s+\\d+[m,n])");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(v);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Ok but what if it isn't exactly connect 5m and the number is variable? So connect 10m or connect 10n should also work.

Comment: you will add data using scanner or from any data variable. it is just for testing. the regex will handle any number then n or m